# Pagination in tabbed list view

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, admin-on-rest

I'm trying to create tabbed list view where I have a filtered list of users in every tab. The problem is that the pagination on the bottom is one for all tabs it doesn't change. When I use it it tries to change the page of all tabs.

What I did is to put List in every Tab and I have a Datagrid in the List.

Is there anything I can do for the pagination?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work unless you rewrite the List component completely.

I suggest you to have a [custom menu](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#menu) instead, with an entry for each of your current tabs and defining the filters in the menu item urls.

Comment: Thank you, this will be the way to go.. I have another question now - what would be the best way to get a resource in custom view?

Comment: Please open a new question for that :)